# $E[X^2|\mathcal{G}]=2\int_0^{\infty}xP(X>x|\mathcal{G})dx$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P),\mathcal{G}$ a sub $\sigma$-algebra. Prove that, almost surely,

$$E[X^2|\mathcal{G}]=2\int_0^{\infty}xP(X>x|\mathcal{G})dx$$
The above formula was true for simple function $X,$ if we pick an increasing function $X_n$ to $X,$ there is a problem in applying the conditional monotone theorem in $\int_0^{\infty}xP(X_n>x)dx$ because $P(X_n>x|\mathcal{G}) \to P(X>x | \mathcal{G})$ on an event $E_x$ (which depends of $x>0$)such that $P(E_x)=1,$ so we can't change interchange limit-integral.

What do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a big issue: For each $x$, $P(X>x \mid \mathcal{G})$ is only determined up to a set of measure zero. If for each $x$, we fix a choice for the random variable $P(X>x \mid \mathcal{G})$, how to guarantee the joint measurability of the map $(x,\omega)\mapsto P(X>x \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega)$?

Comment: You need regular conditional probability or its alike in order to even make sense of the integral in the right-hand side, precisely because of the reason pointed out by other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got a slightly different answer.
Let $P_{\mathcal{G}}$ be your conditional measure (that is $P_{\mathcal{G}}(A)=P(A|\mathcal{G})$), then
$$
E[X^2|\mathcal{G}]= \int X^2 \,dP_{\mathcal{G}}= \int \int_{0}^{\infty}1(X^2>l)\,dl \,dP_{\mathcal{G}} = \int \int_{0}^{\infty}1(|X|>\sqrt{l})\,dl \,dP_{\mathcal{G}}.
$$
Now let $x=\sqrt{l}$ then
$$
E[X^2|\mathcal{G}]=2\int \int_{0}^{\infty}x1(|X|>x)\,dx \,dP_{\mathcal{G}}.
$$
Now use [Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function)'s theorem and interchange the integral to get

$$
E[X^2|\mathcal{G}]=2\int_{0}^{\infty}x\int 1(|X|>x) \,dP_{\mathcal{G}}\,dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty}xP(|X|>x|\mathcal{G})\,dx.
$$

Comment: $P_{\mathcal{G}}$ is it a measure or a random variable ? Or both?

Comment: As you have possibly guessed, it is both. Best.

Comment: So this the regular conditional distribution $P_{|X| | \mathcal{G}}$ which exist but how to deduce from this that there exist a version of $P(|X|>x|\mathcal{G})$ which is $\mathcal{G} \otimes B([0,\infty[)$-measurable?

Comment: Also, it seems you used in the first equality Fubini theorem?

Comment: Let me think but why you would need the measurability of $P(|X|>x|\mathcal{G})$? I understand that you will need measurability of  $x1(|X|>x)$ to apply Tonelli. I will think more and get back to you.

Comment: No, I did not. Simply wrote $X^2$differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120477/discussion-between-suman-chakraborty-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\nu$ denote the regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$. Then for any suitable function $g$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[g(X)\mid \mathcal{G}](\omega)&=\int g(x)\nu(\omega,dx) \\
&=g(0)+\int_0^\infty g'(x)\nu(\omega,(x,\infty))\, dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 g'(x)\nu(\omega,(-\infty,x])\, dx \quad\text{a.s.}
\end{align}
(See, e.g., this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576411/proving-something-similar-to-mathbb-egx-int-0-infty-gx-pxx-dp).)
Now, plug $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: The first line is this a version of Fubini theorem? Also, can't see in the second equality how did you obtain $\nu(w,(x,\infty))$?

Comment: Look at Proposition 10.16 on page 12 [here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf). Also, have you looked at the referenced post? Just replace $\mathsf{P}(X>x)$ with $\nu(\cdot, (x,\infty))$ there.